# Cannot pass parameters to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the following haml code in index.haml

```
%h1.content-header{id: 'content-header'} HEADER
%section.form
  %form.standard{action: some_path, method: 'get'}
    %fieldset.search{'aria-labelledby' => 'content-header'}
      %input{type: 'search', name: 'name', placeholder: 'something', role: 'textbox'} -----(6)
    %fieldset.input-actions
      %input.primary-action{type: 'submit', value: 'search' , name: 'invokeSearch'}
```

I have the following in my controller

```
def index    
   Rails.logger.debug "#{params[:name]}"
    unless @invalid_characters
      unless params[:name].blank?
       ....
       ....
       ....
```

The issue is if i change the name: 'name' in line 6 to say name: 'test' .... `params[:test]` is always blank in my controller. But if i use name: 'name' , params[:name] seems to work . No clue what i am doing wrong here

Comment: Have you tried `render text: params.inspect and return` instead of just debugging one key from `params`? Maybe you changed the file but forgot to reload the page? Have you done "view source" in your browser to be sure that the input field did change in markup?

Comment: tried that and name seems to be test ...

Comment: So you got a situation where params.inspect show the key 'test' but params[:test] is blank?

Comment: {"test"=>nil, "invokeSearch"=>"Search", "action"=>"index", "controller"=>"sources"}

Comment: not sure why it isn't picking up values from the search box

Comment: But doing the same with name actually works

Comment: Where are you defining the `[:text]` param? I can only see you're defining `[:name]` from the view, which will be correct with the controller

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails you should probably benefit from using one of the form helpers for generating the form. For example forms_for that makes you access things in your model directly. It may look like this.

```
= forms_for @thing do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.text_field :test
  = f.submit
```

In this case there will be a map for the model instance in the params map. Something like

```
params[:thing][:name]
```

or

```
params[:thing][:test]
```

you can take that map and pass it into a model to create or update it. If you don't want the tight coupling with the model there is the form_tag method that does much the same thing except you need to be more explicit in what value goes where. And fields ends up directly in params instead of in a model hash.

To see how your params come in you can use the inspect method.

```
puts "params: #{params.inspec}"
```

or install pry to set a break point with

```
binding pry
```

Some ideas. Hope it works out for you. I think you should start with trying to use the rails forms helpers and it will probably sort itself out.